# Best way to "share" data between React files after getting data from Axios Call (post)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, react-hooks

I'm working with React JS in an application that looks like this scheme:

[image: Text]

This application gets the data from an API Rest (Node express) using Axios.
The "problem", is that I'm not sure how is the best way to store the data received from that Axios call (Post), to be able to share that data in the different "files" (page1, page2, page3, ..).

Probably, this can be done by using localStorage, but I know that it's not the proper way (the data received, for example, can be some "user personal data").

I'm coding using functional components and hooks.

For example:

```
//App.js
.. various imports
function App() {
  return(
    <div> 
      <Switch> 
        <Route...> 
        <Route...> 
      </Switch> 
    </div>
  );
} 
return default App;
```

I have been thinking that probably the best way to do this.. Is using some hook (useState) on App file? But I'm not sure if this can work since it's not 100 hierarchical ().. Also, if I perform an Axios call for example on "page 3", that means that I will have to write on "parent" instead of child, no?

Also, I'm not sure if it's the best way.. Or there is another way better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are something new to react, I would use context.

```
<Context.Provider value={this.state.data}>
    <YourApp />
</Context.Provider>
```

On new components get data like this

```
 const { axiosData } = useContext(Context);
```

Context is designed to share data that can be considered "global" to a component tree in React

For more details I would recommend the official documentation
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You have started by "If you are something new to react..". Independently of the experience on react, is "useContext" a good practice in these cases?

Comment: If it is recommended because it is the solution that React offers directly. There is another option called Redux, it is a little better because it has Middelwares, which makes it more powerful, but for that your project must have very specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is some sort of state management for your app. You may want to read up about Redux (or Flux or something else entirely). There's also the Context API which does something similar by allowing you to pass down data to multiple nested components without having to resort to "prop drilling".

Basically with either a Redux or a Context provider your app structure would look like this:

```
<Provider store={reduxStore} /> {/* or <Context.Provider context={myData}> */}
      <Switch> 
        <Route...> 
        <Route...> 
      </Switch> 
</Provider> {/*Context.Provider */}
```

And then the components would be able to hook into the app store (or context) to use the data you want them to watch.